# ifelse with substring R

Tags: r, if-statement, substr

This feels like it should be an easy question, but I have looked here and other places and can't find a simple answer.

I have survey responses and I need to create a 1/0 dummy for source of the response. I am trying to create a simple flag variable by looking through all data in the comment field, and if the substring matches, flag it 1.

Data EG

```
ID     comment
1      rubber chickens
2      180107 RG - email taken from 2017 graduate survey
```

I need R to look through the comment field, and anytime it sees the phrase 'graduate survey' to code my grad_svy field as 1, otherwise 0.

When I write

```
data$grad_svy <- ifelse((substr(data$comment,34,49) == "graduate survey"),1,0)
```

It'll run, but it doesn't mark anything as a 1, when in fact there are hundreds of places it should be marking a 1. I know the two letter phrase begins at 34, and ends at 49, for every instance in the field. I am not sure what I'm not doing, the FAQ for ifelse and substring have been pretty unhelpful.

Comment: are you **sure** you want to start at 34? When I take your second string above I get a space at the beginning; `substr(x,35,49)=="graduate survey"` is `TRUE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this, which uses only base R:

```
data$grad_svy <- as.numeric(grepl("graduate survey", data$comment))
```

`grepl` will return a logical vector if the pattern `"graduate survey"` is found in `data$comment`.  Then using `as.numeric` will convert that logical vector into numbers for you: 1 = `TRUE`, 0 = `FALSE`

Comment: This works quite well, thank you. And thank you very much for adding the second part that explains what the syntax does. I lack a srs programming background, so a lot of what I guess I should know, I just don't for syntax. Thank you for giving the detail.

Comment: Welcome to the community! Don't get discouraged, it takes time, good practice, and patience.  If this answered your question, feel free to accept it as an answer, although there is certainly no obligation to do so.  Happy learning!

Comment: Thanks. I have been a member/lurker for a long time, have lots of experience with analytics, but almost all via SPSS, SAS, STATA, Excel, so no real programming. Hence, a lot of characters and symbols and syntax used by programmers are not familiar to me. Thank you for your help, I appreciate it.

Comment: `+grepl("graduate survey", data$comment)` works as well

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use `grepl` and `data.table` for things like this. For example:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)
data[, grad_svy := as.numeric(grepl("graduate survey", comment))]
```

Comment: You are probably right, it's better, but I am not a programmer, so I can't really read what you mean when you write things like grad_svy := 1 , or [] vs (). You could also say I should know that stuff, but since I don't, I'd rather do it the way I know, even if it's cumbersome, than something I literally have to copy n paste b/c I don't understand the syntax. Thank you for your comment though.

Comment: The `grepl` function, as described below by @Dave, just searches a string for a pattern. i.e. `grepl("a", "and")` will return `TRUE` since the letter "a" is in "and". Everything else is `data.table` syntax.